# MySQL select spatial field value and convert to WKT with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, spatial, geo

If selecting a spatial field value from MySQL without converting it to text in the query, I get an "unreadable" string in PHP. Which function can I use to convert this to WKT?

Example:

```
SELECT AsText(polygon_field) FROM Table; // gives a nice WKT string.
SELECT polygon_field FROM Table; // gives an unreadable (binary?) string.
```

Due to limitations in the framework we use, it would be great if that string could be converted to WKT using PHP. Any ideas on what function to use? Can't seem to find anything, because all examples I find rely on the MySQL function AsText :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the internal format of the column of MySQL ([see the manual on fetching values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fetching-spatial-data.html)). [This format is neither WKB (*well known binary*) nor WKT (*well known text*).](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/supported-spatial-data-formats.html)

I would not expect any other software to be able to parse those values, especially since MySQL provides the helper functions `AsText` and `AsBinary`, which are easy to use (if one does not use a hindering framework).

You can create a view, which contains the `AsText` output of the column as the column itself. This only helps you while selecting, but maybe that is all you need.